# unable to load a site in firefox

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, backbone.js

I have a webpage which works well with chrome.But if i load the same site in Firefox i'm getting the error as below

```
 [HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authorization Required 16ms]
```

I've installed the latest version of firefox,
I'm stuck here and unable to proceed further

Comment: this question has nothing to do with backbone and jquery

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your proxy server has access control .. The following link might help you
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/248020